# time slice per day for two timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I've two timestamps with a gap between a few hours and a few days.
Is there a way in PHP and / or MySQL to get the time slice for every day?

```
INPUT
Timestamp 1: 2013-10-30 10:00:00
Timestamp 2: 2013-10-31 11:00:00

OUTPUT
2013-10-30: 14 hours
2013-10-31: 11 hours
```

Comment: Check the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object of PHP or if they are MySQL timestamps check the DATE_ functions of MySQL to handle date calculations. But its not totally clear for me where you get 14h and 11h from...

Comment: Timestamp 1 is the start. This day (30th) has 14 hours until midnight. The end is timestamp 2. From 0:00 a.m. until 11:00 its 11 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to perform operations on dates is to convert them to timestamps.

Here, what you can do is to get three timestamps :

```php
$ts1 = strtotime("2013-10-30 10:00:00");
$ts2 = strtotime("2013-10-31 00:00:00");
$ts3 = strtotime("2013-10-31 11:00:00");

$first_time_slice = ts2 - ts1; //here you got your first time slice in seconds, convert it to hours
$second_time_slice = ts3 - ts2; //idem for the second time slice
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in MySql like this:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE('2013-10-30 10:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY), '2013-10-30 10:00:00'),
TIMEDIFF('2013-10-31 11:00:00', TIMESTAMP(DATE('2013-10-31 11:00:00')))
```